# Как обновить другую ветку, не переключаясь на нее?

Tags: git

Идея такая, с сделал ветку (например, `branch1`) с `master`'а, поработал в ней и хочу сделать `git rebase master`, но, например, я знаю что `master` был обновлен. Дальше, мне надо делать так:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout branch1
git rebase master
git push ...
```

А возможно ли обновить локального `master`'а не переключаясь с текущей ветки. Что бы можно было сделать одну команду для обновления и сразу `rebase`?

---

**UPDATE**: Попробую внести ясность в вопрос =). Мне было бы очень удобно обновить следящую локальную ветку не переключаясь на нее. Под "обновить" я подразумеваю не только историю коммитов, но и сами локальные файлы, что бы я мог проводить сравнение файлов или `rebase` основываясь на локальной ветке. Другими словами, объединить первые **три** команды в приведенном примере. Но, и это довольно важное "но", по возможности избежать `git checkout master`.

В данном примере, `master` приведен только для некоторой наглядности. В реальном проекте есть несколько веток весьма сильно отличающихся, а кол-во файлов запредельное и поэтому переключение между этими ветками довольно длительная процедура.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
```

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю? `git fetch` обновит мою локальную `master` ветку? Хотя нет, в этой ситуации обновится история и я сделаю `rebase` по новой истории. Правильно?

Comment: @spirit `git fetch` обновит **все** `origin/*`-ветки, но локальные не тронет.

Comment: @D-side Ну да, вернее, он обновит **историю** всех `origin/*` веток. А мне надо обновить именно файлы. Что бы я мог сравнивать, файлы из моей ветки с файлами в ветке `master`

Comment: @spirit файлы в коммитах. Коммиты в ветках. В ответе происходит ребейз на ветку, полученную с сервера, без мерджа её в следящую локальную (что у вас делал `git pull`). По сути, ваш же способ выше, но без лишних шагов из-за лишней ветки. Хотя сам я пользуюсь вашим же способом, т. к. в гите некоторые краткие формы команд опираются на *tracking branch*, и потому я стараюсь поддерживать локальную ветку, следящую за удалённой.

Comment: @spirit операция rebase не требует того, что вы называете "обновлением файлов". Обновления истории достаточно.

Comment: @D-side, вот именно это я и хочу получить: `rebase` и обновление следящей ветки, но без переключения на следящую ветку.
@PavelMayorov, полностью согласен. но хотелось бы именно обновить следящую ветку =)

Comment: @spirit вы сейчас что пытаетесь выяснить? Вам уже дали команды и три раза сказали, что они делают именно то что вам нужно. Вы пробовали их применить?

Comment: я пытаюсь выяснить, можно ли тоже самое сделать одной командой ;)

Comment: @spirit Запишите их через &&

Comment: @spirit ваш вопрос звучит как "обновить другую ветку не переключаясь на нее". Ответ: да, можно обновить `origin/master` с помощью `git fetch`, также можно обновить `master` с помощью `git pull --all`. Было бы странно, если бы всего одной командой выполнялся ещё и rebase какой-то ветки на какую-то другую ветку. Это слишком специфичный случай, чтобы оптимизировать его от двух команд до одной. ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а кто говорит про объединение `rebase`? ;) мне нужно всего лишь обновить следящую ветку не переключаясь на нее. Под "обновить" я подразумеваю не только историю коммитов но и сами локальные файлы, что бы я мог проводить сравнение или rebase основываясь на локальной ветке.

Comment: @spirit для rebase сами файлы не нужны, а для `git diff` можно указать сравниваемые коммиты и файлы в них — но это стоит отдельным вопросом задать.

Comment: @spirit вам уже 4 раза сказали - эти две команды - работают. Команды fetch достаточно для того, чтобы делать rebase. В чем проблема-то?

Answer (score 1):

```
git pull <remote repository name> <remote branch name>:<local branch name>

git pull origin branch_name:branch_name
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]